# Sentence correction - formal

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> What will your office hours be next week?

**or**

> What are your office hours next week?

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider these to both be correct. "What will your office hours be next week?" is a more formal example, while "What are your office hours next week?" is more direct. Good  question!